# Map any collection to its own type, not just Seq?

Tags: scala, generics

Considering this code:

```
def myMap[T, S](seq: S)(implicit ev: S <:< Seq[T]): S =
  seq.map { x => x }
```

The compiler complains:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Seq[T]
required: S
```

Obviously `seq.map { x => x }` returns a `Seq[T]`, instead of `S`.

But `S` is a subclass of `Seq[T]`, and `map` should be able to build an `S` to another `S`.

How to write such a function receiving any `Seq` and return original type, not just `Seq`?

Comment: I think you will have to venture into `CanBuildFrom` territory. If you take a look at full `map` signature, for `List` (for example) it looks like this: `def map[B, That](f: (A) => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That`; that should give you a slight hint.

Comment: @0__ that works but... do I have to write such long code for every single method I want to apply on generic collections?!

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan if you want that method to return the same collection type, yes, you need a builder factory (`CanBuildFrom`).